# How to plot lines between datapoints and the Line of best fit?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the lines between the data points on my linear regression and the line of best fit. Looking to create the grey lines in the attached image.

[image: Image attached here]

Comment: What did you try? Do you have the code for a short test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example.

In summary, the points are a `scatter`, the fit line is computed with [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html), and the vertical segments are a [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# random data
n = 100
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=n)

noise = np.random.normal(0,2,size=n)
Y = X*2+1+noise

# setting up plot
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.scatter(X, Y, c='r', zorder=2)

# computing and plotting fit line
a, b = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)

xs = np.linspace(0,10)
ax.plot(xs, a*xs+b, c='k', lw=2)

# computing and plotting grey lines
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
lines = [[(i,j), (i,i*a+b)] for i,j in zip(X,Y)]
lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors='grey', linewidths=1, zorder=1)
ax.add_collection(lc)
```

Output:

[image: scatter with fit line and vertical lines]

Comment: @ashmathi note that you could also plot the lines one by one using a loop, but it's less efficient